# Как ускорить метод в asyncio и что он делает в python?

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1848   11.927    0.006   11.927    0.006 {built-in method _overlapped.GetQueuedCompletionStatus}
```

Я вывел сколько у меня по времени занимает скрипт это самая наибольшая.
Я использую asyncio aiohttp, и я хотел бы спросить, что это и можно ли это ускорить.
Вызываю функцию через `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())`

Comment: Если я правильно откопал концы, то этот метод ничего особого не делает, он просто ждёт окончания какого-нибудь события ввода-вывода: "Attempts to dequeue an I/O completion packet from the specified I/O completion port. If there is no completion packet queued, the function waits for a pending I/O operation associated with the completion port to complete." Поэтому да - время он тратит, но он в это время ничего не делает, процессор не занимает. Ускорять тут нечего.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asyncio - метод асинхронного воспроизведения программы. Данный метод хорош тем, что если в программу поступает сразу несколько запросов, то он их анализирует и выполняет одновременно. Это увеличивает скорость выполнение программы. Если сравнивать с синхронным выполнением программы на один запрос, то асинхронный уступает, так как выполняется медленнее. Не буду говорить почему именно так происходит, не интересовался так глубоко. Но если поступает на сервер сразу несколько запросов, то в сумме асинхронный код выполнит их быстрее, так как обрабатывает сразу все запросы. Синхронный же в данном случае будет по очереди их выполнять. Поэтому если код не должен принимать сразу несколько запросов, то асинхронный метод ни к чему, так как он медленнее.

Ускорить думаю можно, но это надо видеть сам код, так как скорость зависит больше от того, как код написан.